# wdio async call drops the Selenium connection when invokes a promise call

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, async-await, webdriver-io

Version :       "webdriverio": "^5.7.5",

Apologies in advance if I am not clear, Kindly let me know and can pass my inputs accordingly.

I am running my wdio5 scripts behind corporate proxy. It runs successfully across all browsers. I tried to integrate api calls to the framework and started having multiple issues.

Api libraries like supertest, axios [httpsProxyAgent included], sync-request, then-request are not reading the npm proxy variables used by wdio . Hence I am getting the below error message on API calls

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND qa.internalurl.co.uk
> qa.internalurl.co.uk:443

Api libraries such as - request, fetch-with-proxy makes the API calls successfully by using the proxy settings. I need "await" for their response , hence moving my it block as async function. But after successful response as an async call I am getting the below error message

> [chrome #0-0] $(...).waitForExist is not a function
>
> [chrome #0-0] TypeError: $(...).waitForExist is not a function

Not just waitForExist, the session almost fails to remember any selenium/webdriverio commands. It is clear that it is loosing the selenium connection the moment it switches to an async calls to fetch a promise response.

Is there a way to deal with that?

```
let accountNo = "123456";
it.only('verify the dashboard page ',async () => {
            
            //launches the browser url and cleans the cookies 
            
            try {
                response = await apiCheck.postApiLoginData(accountNo);
  //Makes to call to API function to get the values
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            
            console.log(response);    //prints the successful response data 
            lPage.enterLoginData(accountNo, 'pass1234'); //Fails here as the data is 

            addStep(`Login to the Standard application using username as ${accountNo} and PIN as 74437`);

            lPage.assertSummaryPage(response); 
            
}
```

Without the Try block the code , successfully login to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle non-wdio async code, you need to use [the `browser.call` function](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/call.html). For example:

```
response = browser.call(() => {
    return apiCheck.postApiLoginData(accountNo);
    //Makes to call to API function to get the values
})
```